# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'. while generating APK

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle

I get this error when i try to generate signed APK.

Error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaj;

Build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comp.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'ApiKey', keystoreProperties['Api_Key']

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.24.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Classpath

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
+--- com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.24.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.3
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0 -> 25.3.1
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 -> 11.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0
|    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
          \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
```

Comment: post your `gradlew app:dependencies`

Comment: Check the question

Comment: You posted direct dependencies only. But your question about transitive dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, But i am new to android and don't know what transitive dependencies is and where to find it.

Comment: just run `gradlew app:dependencies` and post output. I want to see section `releaseCompileClasspath`

Comment: Again sorry, but i don't know how to to that.

Comment: I have updated releaseCompileClasspath, please check the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete

```
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```

Because you already added YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar with line

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but could you please try to use for facebook-android-sdk the same version as audience-network-sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your dependencies:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'`

This line will force new ads library. Your `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` forces `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.2`

Comment: Yes, i figured it out. Actually It worked by exclude group:"com.google.android.gms".